# Why works Only one time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've implemented this simple listview to show a button-bar:

```
class _ProductInfoState extends State<ProductInfo> {
  final Map<String, dynamic> product;
  _ProductInfoState(this.product);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ButtonBar> bdata = new List<ButtonBar>();
    final Color kcolor2d = Color(int.parse(product['color']['second']));
    final Color kcolor1t = Color(int.parse(product['color']['first']));
    final Map<String, dynamic> types = product['types'];
    types.forEach((k, v) {
      bdata.add(new ButtonBar(false, v['title'], kcolor1t, kcolor2d));
    });
    bdata[0].isSelected = true;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kcolor2d,
        title: Text(tr(product['name'])),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox.expand(
              child: Container(
            color: kcolor2d,
          )),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20,
              top: 10,
              bottom: 10,
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 35,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular((5.0)),
                  color: kcolor1t,
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: bdata.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                           for (var i = 0; i < bdata.length; i++) {
                              bdata[i].isSelected = false;
                            }
                            bdata[index].isSelected = true;
                            print("Clicked " + bdata[index].buttonText);
                          });
                        },
                        child: ButtonBarItem(bdata[index]));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ButtonBarItem is implemented like:

```
  final ButtonBar _item;
  ButtonBarItem(this._item);
  @override
  _ButtonBarItem createState() => _ButtonBarItem(_item);
}

class _ButtonBarItem extends State<ButtonBarItem> {
  final ButtonBar _item;
  _ButtonBarItem(this._item);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 30,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _item.isSelected ? Colors.white70 : _item.kcolor1t,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
            child: Text(_item.buttonText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: _item.isSelected ? _item.kcolor2d : Colors.white,
                ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonBar {
  bool isSelected;
  final String buttonText;
  final Color kcolor2d;
  final Color kcolor1t;
  ButtonBar(this.isSelected, this.buttonText, this.kcolor1t, this.kcolor2d);
}
```

and showes like that:
[ButtonBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5xKX.png)

At first click it works properly and changes the background color, but if I click again not working though the variable isSelected is correctly updated.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Add ```bdata = [...bdata]``` as the last line in your ```setState``` and update me ?

Comment: Tried but not work.

Comment: You putted it directly after ```print```right ?

Comment: Right, in past I had a similar problem and it was caused by scoping. But I can't remember the exact problem.

Comment: Replace your ```forEach``` by ```for``` loop, this might works for you

Comment: Probably this will work, confirm this in order to post it as an answer with some details

Comment: why changing the iteration loop would change the result?

Comment: This is because element is considered as local variable, updating element will not update the real item in the list,After the loop, element just gets garbage collected. and the list will be the same before the loop, but using ```for``` loop, you will access and change directly the real element not just acopy

Comment: unsuccessful operation. that didn't work either.

Comment: Update your code

Comment: Update with full code of class

Comment: please last thing, add ```bdata = [...bdata]``` before the print as I told you before.

Comment: Nothing to do. Same result, I can't understand.

Comment: Make sens now, ```setState``` will call ```build``` , and you are initiating the array inside the ```build```, move the code before the ```return``` to ```initState```

Comment: Just tried: now all work properly. Thanks man

Comment: I will share it as answer, You can accept it so others may avoid this issue for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps to fix the problem:

1. You are initiating the array inside the `build`, move the code before the `return` to `initState`
2. Use `for` lop instead of `forEach` : This is because element is considered as local variable, updating element will not update the real item in the list,After the loop, element just get garbage collected. and the list will be the same before the `forEach`, but using for loop, you will access and change directly the real element not just a copy